# Firebase chat app not displaying proper online status in action bar subtitle - solutions?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Online status not updating correctly in Kotlin Firebase chat app

I'm facing an issue with my Kotlin Firebase chat app where the online status is not updating correctly in the action bar subtitle. Even when a user goes offline, the app still displays the online status.

NOTE: In realtime database i can see the online status changing from True to false

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
val lastSeenRef = userRef.child(currentUserUid).child("presence").child("lastSeen")
        lastSeenRef.setValue(sdf.format(Date()))

// Update online value
        onlineRef = userRef.child(currentUserUid).child("presence").child("online")
        onlineRef.setValue(true)

        
        // Update the online status to false when the user disconnects
        onlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(false)
        userRef.child(currentUserUid).child("presence").child("online")
        onlineRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val online = snapshot.value as Boolean
                //onlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(false)
                val lastSeen = snapshot.child("lastSeen").getValue(String::class.java) 
                val subtitle = if (online) {
                    "Online"
                } else {
                    //val lastSeen = snapshot.child("lastSeen")
                    "Last seen $lastSeen"
                }
                supportActionBar?.subtitle = subtitle

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Handle error
            }
        })
```

Comment: "Even when a user goes offline, the app still displays the online status." How long did you wait? For dirty disconnects (i.e. cases where the client doesn't have a chance to call the server before its connection is closed) it may take a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone.

Comment: I waited for longer than a few minutes, but it still shows online. I also tried to check on the user who hasn't logged in for a couple of days, but it still shows online.

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Have you also tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something went wrong?